# file, modify and store

Tags: python-3.x, file

Today I use python to edit a text.What I can do only read and write.When I use write by the model 'w', it covers the last file.As the same time,I remember the editor 'word'.In our life,every time we modify a text,and save in the same file like 'Control+S'.This action is covering the file before?

I think what the computer can do to a text is not modifying but reading  and writing.Can you tell me what I think is true or false and share your knowledge with me?

At last,My English is poor ,sorry  --||，but I want to know it. 3Q

Comment: Do you want to know if file can be modified / appended to, without having to completely overwrite it?

Comment: I wonder if the action is overwrite the same as I think when I modify a file and store